# Design-pattern for building reading/writing packages

Tags: design-patterns

Let me introduce some initial points:
I work with program that is connecting via uart (to the special board) and sending data packages to set/get information about devices in the special board' network. Package format looks like:

```
|Start byte | Device ID | R/W | Parameter| Data | CRC|
```

So I have several devices and want to generate data packages in the most efficient way. My question: is there any appropriate design pattern to generate packages above? Of course it could be hardcoded, but I try to found more flexible way.

Comment: Could it be that what you want is an old and trusty data structure? Or just an object that knows how to serialise itself (and maybe parse) in the correct format?

Comment: @Augusto yes, I have started with doing device classes derived from the "abstract device" class. I suppose that classes could know their ID and available parameters to be read/written. I am going to parse answered messages by going through the list of devices and comparing their ID and so on. Is it a common and a right way?

Comment: You don't define efficiency, in what way you need your protocol to be efficient? There are many protocols out there you could use but based on what metric are you going to compare them? Look, for instance at Modbus RTU.

Comment: @MarcosG. I use the certain protocol and talk "efficiency" about parsing in/out messages. I mean, e.g. there are four devices and I could write function parsing incoming packages with "cases" (If device ID=0, then parse it this way, if device ID = 1, then parse it another way, etc.). Then another device could be added, so I will need to rewrite this function. Under "efficiency" in my case I consider the flexible way to parse messages from devices and create command messages to devices.

Answer (score 0):

For writing you could use one of the Creational Bulder patterns. Like Simple or Fluent Builder. For reading you could use one of the Behavioural Interpreter patterns, like Interpreter or Parser.

But your task is utmost simple. So, I strongly recommend to create a straightforward class and implement the necessary data structures an read/write methods. This seems to be the more efficient solution.

If your data structure is more complex, you may use one of the above patterns. But also here, reusing an existing protocol is simpler.

Please consider